# Send multiple parameters to popup

Tags: javascript, model-view-controller, kendo-ui

I'm using Kendo. I want to open a popup. How can I send multiple parameters to it?

```
onDetail: function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            var dataItem = this.dataItem($(e.currentTarget).closest("tr"));

            vm.dialogBox = $('<div id="details-box"/>').appendTo('body');
            vm.dialogBox.kendoWindow({
                iframe: true,
                content: 'Sample',
                title: 'جزئیات',
                close: function (e) {
                    alert('Closing...');
                    vm.dialogBox.remove();
                }
            });
            vm.dialogBox.data('kendoWindow').open().maximize();

            return false;
        }
```

Comment: content: Parameter_1+" "+ Parameter_2,

Comment: @DilipBelgumpi, Thanks a lot. Worked fine.